# Overloading operator << , os gets a string

Tags: c++, string, class, operator-overloading, ostream

so I have problem with my code, I want to overload operator <<, all the functions are in abstract class Employee so

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Employee &employee) {
    os<<employee.print();
    return os;
}
```

That's a function print:

```
virtual const std::string& print() const {
   return "description: "+this->description+ " id: "+ std::to_string(this->getID()); }
```

Description and ID just a variables in class Employee

And it just doesn't work and I get exception E0317, I understand it like what print returns it's not a string.
Also, if I change return type to

```
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>
```

it magically works, but I don't understand why I can't use standard string.

Comment: Please include a [mcve], ie if "it doesn't matter" then remove it from the example, but add enough so it can be compiled and reproduces the problem

Comment: not the problem, but dont you think your `print` should rather be called `to_string`?

Comment: When you changed the type did you also remove the `&`?

Comment: IMO, better to have `void print(std::ostream& os) const;` member function, and call it as `employee.print(os);` from the `operator<<` freestanding function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`const std::string& print() const`

This returns a reference to a temporary string, which goes out of scope as soon as it's created and the reference you use outside the function is therefore invalid.

To make it work in the situation you currently use the function, you need to change it to:

`const std::string print() const`

An even better solution would be to also drop `const` on the return value since making changes to the returned `std::string` can *not* affect the `Employee` object. There's no reason to *try* to restrict future users of the `print()` function if they want to `std::move` the returned string or make changes to it in other ways.

So, this would be a better signature:

`std::string print() const`

As [formerlyknownas_463035818](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/formerlyknownas-463035818) implied in a comment, this function doesn't really have anything to do with printing. It returns a string representation of the object so `to_string` would indeed be a more appropriate name.